# How to adjustTCP/networking options on windows 8.1?

Tags: php, linux, windows, networking, web-frameworks

I am now busy with a PHP- frameworks benchmarking. There is already a benchmarking script for it, you can find it here https://github.com/kenjis/php-framework-benchmark
I have done that on my Ubuntu machine, and I got good results.

I want now to run the benchmarking on my windows 8.1 machine. The problem is I don't know how to configure TCP like I did on Linux. 
These changes must be done to the kernel of linux:

```
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 100000
net.nf_conntrack_max = 100000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 180000
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 10
```

To do that I should put those changes above to /etc/sysctl.conf. 
I want to make the same changes on Windows, but I don't know where can I do that. 
Can anyone help me?!

Comment: You'll have to do it trough windows registry. Here's an example for TCP/IP maximum retransmission time-out https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170359

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.